Which columns/entities do the hashes contained in the article.products column in Shopware 6 point to?
I am looking to migrate a Shopware v6.3.5.4 installation to Odoo and am familiar with neither Shopware or Odoo.  I am trying to create a SQL script that will return product<>article relationships from my Shopware DB dump which I will then import into Odoo.
The article table contains a column named products of type TEXT.  In my installation, the column contains comma separated lists which appear to be hashes (which I assume point to at least the product table).
To which entity(s) do these hashes point and how/where in the Shopware codebase are these mappings technically created? (I understand that these relationships can at least be administered via the Marketing > Articles backend UI.)
I have so far created an ERD via reverse engineering in MySQL Workbench but this only confirms that that the article table is related to the article_media and article_translation tables.
